# simple ajax call in joomla 1.5 not working

Tags: ajax, joomla, mootools

I'm trying to do a simple ajax call in joomla 1.5 (from the jseblod subtemplate, if that's any help) but nothing seems to work:
I tried using javascript and using mootools (version is 1.1) to call a simple test.php file but all I get is the whole website displayed again in the targeted div. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('start').addEvent('click', function(e) {
e = new Event(e).stop();

var url = "test.php";
new Ajax(url, {
    method: 'get',
    update: $('ajax-container')
}).request();
});
</script>
```

and the HTML part:

```
<h3>Simple Ajax Request</h3>
<a id="start" href="#">Click here</a>
<div id="ajax-container"></div>
```

and I also tried this using Mootools:

```
<?php
$url = "test.php";
$ajax = <<<EOD
window.addEvent('domready',function() 
{
$('drop-down').addEvent('change',function()
{ 
      var a = new Ajax({$url},{
           method:'get',
           update: $('ajax-container')
           }
      }).request();
    });
});
EOD;
$doc = & JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration( $ajax );
?>
```

Comment: using mootools 1.1 is not a good plan. at all. you want at least 1.3 or you will have nasty compat issues with ie9 and ff19. your second example has a syntax error (surplus `}` and `})`) anyway. not sure if the `update` mutator was supported back then - check the 1.11 docs.

Comment: But what about the first syntax then - it doesn't use Mootools and it still doesn't work? I can't change the version because of other problems unfortunately.
PS I tried changing the second syntax, still nothing

Comment: first example is also mootools - Ajax is the Request wrapper in 1.11

Comment: I got this to work with jQuery in the end - much simpler also, will post the code later

Comment: Well its not more simple in jQuery, just maybe easier to you if you already know jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone interested, here is the code using jQuery 1.8.3 library, which is simply loaded in the first line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("#div1").load("http://www.panacea.hr/test.php");
});
});
</script>
<button>Start AJAX</button>
<div id="div1"><h3>Place for generated content</h3></div>
```

And here is the start of my test.php - this code is needed to connect to database and perform queries, because Joomla doesn't see the test.php as a part of the site:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
// query after this
```